# Sortable AND update multiple hidden fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, hidden-field

Good morning,

I have built a fairly simple system that allows me to 'build' emails using php and jQuery.

The page runs through a 1-20 loop and for each number, there's a table that contains the number and a checkbox next to each number. Once the checkbox is selected, a second table appears with a dropdown to allow me to choose the 'type' of content required for each section.

There are multiple options available to choose from e.g. 1 image, 2 images, text block etc - once selected, a set of form fields are un-hidden relating to the option you've chosen. Supply the form with image names, alt text, url's etc and then press a submit button and the content is fed through to another page where the html is generated.

The end result then could be:

section_1 : 1 image (header.jpg) - goes to homepage

section_2 : 1 image (sale.jpg) - goes to sale page

section_3 : 1 image (new.jpg) - goes to new page

sections 4 - 20 : left un-checked and therefore content remains hidden and the variables are not passed.

I want to be able to reorder the sections using sortable, but have the id's update in the background.

So, in the above example, visible, I have:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Section_1_Checkbox" name="Section_1_Checkbox" value="yes">
```

Then there's a select:

```
<select id="Section_1_Select" name="Section_1_Select">
    <option value="Section_1_hide">please choose</option>
    <option value="Section_1_main" selected="">one image</option>
    <option value="Section_1_twoup">two images</option>
    <option value="Section_1_text">text box</option>
    <option value="Section_1_gap">add a gap</option>
    .....
</select>
```

and then:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" class="show_Section_1_main" style="display:block;" shown="shown">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="formstyle mainstyle" valign="top">
                <label for="Section_1_main_image_gap">px gap below image</label><input type="text" size="2" name="Section_1_main_image_gap" id="Section_1_main_image_gap" value="0" class="otherfield">
                <label for="Section_1_main_image_gap2">px gap above image</label><input type="text" size="2" name="Section_1_main_image_gap2" id="Section_1_main_image_gap2" value="0" class="otherfield"><br> 
                <br>
                <div style="width:604px; float:left;">

                    <img id="Section_1_main_image_box" src="mailer_images/header.jpg" style="max-width:594px; max-height:250px;">
                    <br>
                    <label for="Section_1_main_image">paste image name here</label><br>
                    <input type="text" size="77" name="Section_1_main_image" id="Section_1_main_image" value="header.jpg" class="imagechange">
                    <br>
                    <label for="Section_1_main_image_url">full url</label><br>
                    <input type="text" size="77" name="Section_1_main_image_url" id="Section_1_main_image_url" value="http://www.urlhomepage.com" class="otherfield">
                    <br>
                    <label for="Section_1_main_image_alt">alt text</label><br>
                    <input type="text" size="77" name="Section_1_main_image_alt" id="Section_1_main_image_alt" value="alt text for homepage" class="otherfield">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have looked at various examples and jsFiddles, but being fairly new to jQuery, i'm a bit lost...

So the basic question is:

If i'm moving Section_3 to the top, how do I change the ID's of ALL the other fields (including hidden ones) so that my sections are still passed through in the orders 1 - 20, but the content has changed.

Sorry if that doesn't make sense. Happy to answer any questions.

Thanks in advance,

Rachael

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is... Is it "how to you change the id of an element using jQuery"? If that't the case, it's $('#old-id').attr('id', 'new-id');. If you need to change a bunch, just iterate through them and make changes. If that's not what you're asking, please be more specific with your problem.

Comment: Hi. I knew what i'd written wasn't clear! Sorry...

Comment: Basically, I want to move the table of form fields as my sortable element. I want to then update the ID's of all child form fields within that table. So if i'm moving a table for section_3 up to the top, I want to update all relevant id's that WERE section_3 to now be section_1 (and in turn, update all other elements accordingly so that they're all correct. i.e. 1 now becomes 2, 2 now becomes 3)

Comment: Please make a fiddle with what you have right now.

Comment: For now, the simplest way of explaining what I want is here: http://jsfiddle.net/ha7d64es/1/

When an item is moved, I want the values and id's of the text boxes to update to be in sequential order...

So when you move item 1 to be in position 3, that's fine, but the text boxes and id's still say 1 - 6, rather than 2.3.1.4.5.6 - if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgeh4j5f/) with the solution based on the example you posted in the comment.

```
var listElements = $('.sortable li');
// iterate through all the list items
for(var i = 0; i < listElements.length; i++){
    // save the children elements of the current list element
    var children = $(listElements[i]).children();
    // change the id of the list element
    $(listElements[i]).attr('id', i+1);
    // change the text of the list element
    $(listElements[i]).text('item ' + (i+1));
    // put the children back (changing text deleted them)
    $(listElements[i]).append(children);
    // change the id and the value of the input element
    $(listElements[i]).children('input').attr({
        id: 'position_' + (i+1), 
        value: i+1
    });
}
```

Basically, when sorting is finished, `update` event of sortable widget is being called. In it, you should iterate through the elements you wish to change, and change them them using `attr` and/of `text` methods.

EDIT: 
You can split old id into array, and than reconstruct it from that array into the new one. Of course, in that case all the ids need to have the same structure.

```
var oldId = $(listElements[i]).children('input').attr('id').split('_');
$(listElements[i]).children('input').attr({
    id: oldId[0] + '_' + (i+1) + '_' + oldId[2], 
    value: i+1
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! That's hopefully just what I need to start looking at this more in-depth... There's going to be a whole bunch of stuff that needs to get updated, but for now, this gives me a great place to start!

Comment: After a bit of a tweak, this is sort of the thing I meant.
http://jsfiddle.net/913pyarx/1/

With my email builder, there will be form elements that contain data about what's happening within the section. I don't want the content to change, simply the order in which they are on the page. My form will always submit values 1-20 and a separate page relies on the information being passed through in sequential order. With jQuery, I hope to simply 'swap' the content from 1 section to another without changing the id's. Thanks again. Rachael

Comment: Just a quick question, before I start another post... I've done a bit of an update to that fiddle, and I realise that in my initial example, I had my ID's as "position_1", "position_2", "position_3" etc. as opposed to what they will ACTUALLY look like, which is more like: "position_1_imagename", "position_2_url", "position_3_alt". What I'm looking to do is update the position number as the item order is changed, but I can't really see how to do this. I've tried using a simple 'replace' function,  but that's not working. Any ideas? New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/913pyarx/2/

Comment: Ignore that. All sorted using split and some other bits. Thanks!